# How do I turn off check boxes?

Tags: html, css, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I want to have a two check boxes behave as if they were radio buttons. When one is checked, I want the other to turn off. I am using ColdFusion `<CFForm>`. Another option would be to use a radio button tag but have them look like check boxes. Any suggestions?

Comment: If you are making check boxes work like radio buttons, it would be best to just use radio buttons for the user experience.

Comment: Is the concern that you want to be able to uncheck all of the items which can't be done with just 2 radio buttons?

Comment: `CFFORM` won't be any help with making that functionality happen. It's just concerned with basic form validation. You'll need to write your own JavaScript and have it manage the `click` events for the checkboxes. This can run independently of the CF generated JavaScript.

Comment: What is the use case?

Answer (score 10):

> Another option would be to use a radio button tag but have them look like check boxes. Any suggestions?

Don't. There's a reason checkboxes behave like checkboxes and radio buttons behave like radio buttons.  If you introduce a deviation from this you'll just confuse your users who have been trained for years that this is the way these controls behave.  If you want radio button functionality, use radio buttons.